# Inverse Fourier Transform of Poisson Characteristic Function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, fourier-analysis

The follow line is returning without evaluation:

```
 InverseFourierTransform[
     CharacteristicFunction[PoissonDistribution[1], t], t, w]
```

It is meant to output the probability mass function of the Poisson distribution with unit mean.

I can't find the calculation anywhere online. I assume this doesn't evaluate because of the discrete nature of the Poisson distribution? Are there some assumption I need to add?

Comment: `PDF[PoissonDistribution[1], w]` does what you want, no?

Comment: Yes that works. So do other inverse Fourier transforms, including the characteristic function of the Gaussian.